# Add 'hide field' control toggle to ACF Fields for easy user hiding

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to add a custom control (button or toggle) to an Advanced Custom Fields group, where it can be hidden from the front-end with a toggle or a button? I am trying to add a user friendly way to allow the client to hide a block of info at their leisure.

I don't really have a code example as it's really just a general question. I do a lot of custom ACF pro layouts, and I user their docs and ACF awesome quite a bit. I have just never heard of this being used and it seems like a simple thing that clients always ask for. Just wondering what your guys' experiences are with this?

Comment: ACF Pro's True/False feature will do that, and works well if you use the stylized UI option: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/ Take a look at their documentation and let me know if you still have specific questions.

Comment: Thanks so much ludditedev !
ACF Pro's True/False feature sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I will give it a try now. 
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/ . .

If you want to go ahead and post your comment as an answer I can say this is solved and close this since that alone gives me loads to go off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely easy to do, just create another field thats a radio button for example or a checkbox both work. In my example i would use a field called example_toggle:

For a checkbox:

```
<?php if( !in_array( 'hide', get_field('example_toggle') ) ):?>
    insert your acf code that you wish to display
<?php endif;?>
```

This will check example_toggle it checks to make sure that the "hide" box has not been checked (!in_array = not in array), if it isn't found then it will execute the block. Otherwise if selected to "hide" it will not execute the code and therefore hides the block.

For a radio button:

```
<?php if( get_field('example_toggle') == 'show' ):?>
    insert your acf code that you wish to display
<?php endif;?>
```

Same explanation however, it can only have 1 option so it doesn't need to check an array it justs needs to check the value, I also use "show" in this example but  "hide" can be used if you change == to !==

For true/false:

```
<?php if( get_field('example_toggle') ): ?>
    insert your acf code that you wish to display
<?php endif;?>
```

Same explanation however less code required for True/False as true = 1 false = 0 it will only trigger when the value is true.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much.

Comment: Thanks again, I couldn't get the checkbox or radio to work, but T/F worked perfect. Thanks so much. You're right it was very easy :)

Comment: So, must use php to do this? No way to toggle on/off a field just in backend?